# Applications for holomorphic functions?

Tags: functions

Could anyone give me an insight into practical applications of holomorphic functions (I am using the term in the way in which it is related to Riemann's work)?

Comment: Holomorphic functions are not very interesting by themselves. Most physical applications involves the theory of residue which doesn't exist for holomorphic functions. Perhaps the only application I can see is that since holomorphic functions satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation, we can use those equations to model fluid flow and maybe fields in electrostatics.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of possible applications of the extension of the analytical domain

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant, your comment seems mostly misguided.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Enlighten me :) Most problem I deal with requires residue, how interesting can holomorphic function be if most things they are involved with come out to be 0?

Answer (score 6):

A very interesting consequence of holomorphic functions is that as they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, they automatically satisfy Laplace's equation. Because of this, we can model 2-D potential fluid flow based on holomorphic functions. For example fluid flowing past a cylinder of radius $a$ can be imagined by taking constant values of the imaginary part of the complex function $$\Omega(z) = U\left(z+\frac{a^2}{z}\right)$$ resulting in this fluid flow:

[image]

where the streamline in blue visualises the dividing streamline where stagnation points occur on the solid body.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? I can't see why modelling potential flow isn't a valid application.